# ValueError: could not convert string to float: s

Tags: python, error-handling

I have the following code. When I enter a letter character for " Scale = float(raw_input("Please enter '1' for Fahrenheit and '2' for Celsius: "))" in while loop, I receive "ValueError: could not convert string to float: s" error. At the same time, when I press 1 or 2 which is required. I receive "Invalid option is entered" which should pop up in case any character other 1 or 2 is entered. Could you please assist me with this? Thanks a lot.

```
import socket, sys, os
Arguments = sys.argv

Host = (Arguments[1])
Port = (int(Arguments[2]))


try:
    Server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    Server.connect((Host,Port))
except socket.error, (value,message):
    if Server:
        Server.close() 
    print "Failed to create the socket: " + message
    sys.exit(1) 

while(True):
    Scale = float(raw_input("Please enter '1' for Fahrenheit and '2' for Celsius: "))
    if ((Scale != 1)) or ((Scale != 2)):
        print ("\nInvalid option is entered.")
    else:
        Server.sendall(Scale)
        break
```

Comment: Try evaluating that `or` by hand, one piece at a time.

Comment: Replace `if ((Scale != 1)) or ((Scale != 2))` by `if Scale not in (1,2)`.  (n.b. you could also only replace the `or` by `and`).